# Making directive scope unique per each directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a component that builds form fields dynamically using Angular (which I am new to).

The controller contains data of the form fields I will be viewing as follows in `mainModel` :

```
angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    // build the scope dynamically 
    $scope.mainModel = {
        "category_id": {
            "name": "category_id",
                "value": "1",
                "label": "Category Id"
        },
            "category_name": {
            "name": "category_name",
                "value": "First Category",
                "label": "Category Name"
        });

}]).directive('formLoader', function ($compile) {

    function link(scope, ele, attrs) {

        var html = '';
        jQuery.each(scope.mainModel, function (key, value) {
            //display the key and value pair
            console.log(key + ' --------------- ' + value);

            if (key == 'category_id' || key == 'category_name') {
                html += "<br />Testing<br /><kad-Input properties='mainModel." + key + "'></kad-Input>"
            }

        });

        var x = angular.element(html);
        ele.append(x);
        $compile(x)(scope);

    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        link: link
    };

}).directive('kadInput', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //transclude: true,
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: 'tests.html',
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {

            scope.properties = $parse(attrs.properties)(scope);
            console.log(scope.properties);

        }
    };
});
```

The idea is to loop through the mainModel and build the form dynamically based on the main Model, this is the job of the `formLoader` directive which is the only thing I will be calling in my HTML.

I have created a directive `kadInput` (just for testing) that resembles a "label : text input" html as follows :

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 bottom-10" >
    <h4 class="header_label" ><label for="productName"> {{properties.label}} </label></h4>
</div>  

<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12" >
    <input type="text" id="productName" ng-model="properties.value" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

I am getting the result needed but the problem is that the `scope.properties` of `kadInput` is not unique by directive, it is only taking the data that is being last set to it.

How can I make the scope unique per directive keeping the same aspect of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a lot of things unnecessarily here that Angular directives do *for* you. I would recommend you do a thorough reading of the [directives guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)—it's very easy to understand.

The relevant point here is the idea of an "isolate scope", which you're explicitly opting out of by using `scope: false` (which does nothing, by the way), and then reading from `attrs` manually, which is mostly just negating what directives are designed to do.

What you *want* is to pass an object to `scope` that will specify that you want an isolate scope with a single parameter:

```
scope: {
  properties: '='
}
```

This will set up the data-binding for you, and it will keep the scopes unique between instances of your directive.

Comment: I have had some concepts mixed up... but now you got it clear for me thanks man..

Comment: oops (* ^ ∀ ^ *) .. Thank you lady :)